# Can't test if radio buttons are rendered React Testing Library and Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm working on a synthesizer (music instrument) in React. The interface of the instrument needs some radio buttons so users can change how it works (e.g. choosing a waveform which is sort of the base sound). As part of this personal project I want to test the functioning of the synth with Jest to avoid clicking a lot and changing contexts between the browser and my text editor.

The problem is radio buttons can't be found by Jest even though their name is specified in the assertion. Meaning, `` expect(screen.getAllByRole(`radio`).length).toBe(4); `` doesn't have any problem at all, `` expect(screen.getByRole(`radio`,{name:`sine`})).toBeInTheDocument(); `` does throw an error in the console.

Test:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import {cleanup,getByTestId,render,screen, waitFor} from '@testing-library/react';
import Carrier from './carrier';
import Settings from './settings.json'

beforeEach(()=>{
  cleanup();
})

describe(`Rendering`, ()=>{

  it(`renders waveform type radio buttons`,()=>{
    render(<Carrier settings={Settings}/>);
    expect(screen.getAllByRole(`radio`).length).toBe(4);
  });

  it(`checks radio buttons label match waveform types`,()=>{
    render(<Carrier settings={Settings}/>);
    expect(screen.getByRole(`button`,{name:`sine`})).toBeInTheDocument(); 
  });
});
```

Output:

```
    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "button" and name "sine"

    Here are the accessible roles:

      group:

      Name "Waveform":
      <fieldset />

      --------------------------------------------------
      radio:

      Name "":
      <input
        data-testid="sine"
        name="sine"
        type="radio"
      />

      Name "":
      <input
        name="triangle"
        type="radio"
      />

      Name "":
      <input
        name="square"
        type="radio"
      />

      Name "":
      <input
        name="sawtooth"
        type="radio"
      />
```

Component:

```
const Carrier = ({settings}) =>{
  return(
    <>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Waveform</legend>
        <label htmlFor='sine'>sine</label>
        <input data-testid='sine' name='sine' type='radio'/>
        <label htmlFor='triangle'>triangle</label>
        <input name='triangle' type='radio'/>
        <label htmlFor='square'>square</label>
        <input name='square' type='radio'/>
        <label htmlFor='sawtooth'>sawtooth</label>
        <input name='sawtooth' type='radio'/>
      </fieldset>
    </>
  );
}

export default Carrier;
```

Attempts:

1. Checked a similar line of code with `button` element and the test is successful
2. Used `waitFor` inside an `async` test to wait till the button was present on the DOM
3. `getByTestID` works fine but I don't like that way since there are lots of radio buttons
4. Removed `` {name:`sine`} `` and the console told me there was more than one button in the Document

Questions:

1. Why doesn't name appear in the console output? I've checked some similar questions on the internet (there are very few) and there shouldn't be a problem with `` expect(screen.getByRole(`radio`,{name:`sine`})).toBeInTheDocument(); ``
2. What am I missing in my code?

Comment: Your labels and inputs aren't connected, hence roles but no accessible names. I'd suggest enabling the jsx-a11y linting rules.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jonrsharpe! I made changes in my code the way you suggested and that worked and I'm gonna post them as the answer to the question. I've got a beginner question though, why did you edit the question in that way? Isn't markdown the preferred format for programmers? Oh and why did the question a down vote?  BTW I'll check how to enable jsx-a11y linting rules on vim.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jonrshape's suggestion I connected my labels with their respective radio buttons properly in the following way:

```
const Carrier = ({settings}) =>{
  return(
    <>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Waveform</legend>
          <label>
           <input name='sine' type='radio'/>
            sine
          </label>
          <label>
           <input name='square' type='radio'/>
            square
          </label>
          <label>
           <input name='triangle' type='radio'/>
            triangle
          </label>
          <label>
           <input name='sawtooth' type='radio'/>
            sawtooth
          </label>
      </fieldset>
    </>
  );
}

export default Carrier;
```

Tests passed without a problem

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import {cleanup,getByTestId,render,screen, waitFor} from '@testing-library/react';
import Carrier from './carrier';
import Settings from './settings.json'

beforeEach(()=>{
  cleanup();
})

describe(`Rendering`, ()=>{

  it(`renders waveform type radio buttons`,()=>{
    render(<Carrier settings={Settings}/>);
    expect(screen.getAllByRole(`radio`).length).toBe(4);
  });

  it(`checks radio buttons label match waveform types`,()=>{
    render(<Carrier settings={Settings}/>);
    expect(screen.getByRole(`radio`,{name:`sine`})).toBeInTheDocument(); 
    expect(screen.getByRole(`radio`,{name:`square`})).toBeInTheDocument(); 
    expect(screen.getByRole(`radio`,{name:`triangle`})).toBeInTheDocument(); 
    expect(screen.getByRole(`radio`,{name:`sawtooth`})).toBeInTheDocument(); 
  });
});
```